# BundleConfig returns 302 / 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

I can't for the life of me understand why my project developed this issue.

I am using the **.Net Framework 4.7.1**. My bundle is defined as follows:

```
var styleBundle = new StyleBundle("~/assets/sass/aaaa").Include(
    "~/assets/sass/main.css"
);

// This transform adds a randomized version number to the end of the bundle name
styleBundle.Transforms.Add(new FileHashVersionBundleTransform());

bundles.Add(styleBundle);
```

And in the Layout page:

```
@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/assets/sass/aaaa")
```

The request results in a 302 that is then redirect to my 404 error page.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

A previous version (one week old) of my codebase running on a separate Application Pool works without issues, but in the main branch all my bundles no longer work.

EDIT: I already browsed the other questions on this same topic on this site and elsewhere. I attempted all the suggested changes to the Application Pool and Web.config, with no luck whatsoever.

Comment: Everything looks correct to me, except you are not telling us what is `FileHashVersionBundleTransform` doing. By the way, you could use the shorter: `@Styles.Render("~/assets/sass/aaaa")` to render the style (though this has nothing to do with the problem).

Comment: Indeed the same code works perfectly in a different project. The FileHashVersionBundleTransform simply adds a randomized ?v=<number>

Comment: I would just comment out the transform to make sure it is not causing the problem... I am not sure why you have added it at the first place

Comment: I added to make sure that those bundles will not be cached during development. And yes, it makes no difference.

Comment: I would make sure that your bundle name does not clash with a physical folder.  You have a bundle name `assets/sass`, but are drawing the files from `assets/sass`.  Change your bundle name (e.g. to `bundle/sass`) and see how you go.

Comment: I tried that many, many times. Different folders, different CSS/JS file. I have now went as far as stripping everything else from the solution - every other Project, every other reference, any non-basic System dll and code file, to make the project just a BundleConfig.cs file and a .cshtml page. To no avail - I cannot think of anything that could cause this. It's maddening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is Sitecore-specific. The /assets path was not included in the IgnoreUrlPrefixes, a Sitecore configuration field that is used to single out URL prefixes that should be exception to the default Sitecore routing.

This was causing my bundling to fail.